# How to put a DataTrigger inside GridControl Table View?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger, devexpress-wpf

I need a Datatrigger inside a tableview of a Gridcontrol. How to put a working DataTrigger inside the View. I want to change the foreground of Data if it is a negative number. Here is a sample of code

```
 <dxg:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:TableView NavigationStyle="Row" ShowTotalSummary="True" ShowFixedTotalSummary="True" AutoWidth="True">
                      <dxg:TableView.RowStyle>
                            <Style >
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Data, Converter={StaticResource NegativeNumConveter}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>

                            </Style>
                      </dxg:TableView.RowStyle>
                    </dxg:TableView>
```

Comment: So far I only see a statement, not a question?

Comment: @ChrisW. better now?

Comment: I have the same issue with row style and datatrigger. Have you found any solution?